# Oracle Instant Client link error when building on OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, oracle, gcc

I am trying to compile a simple Oracle application on OS X and running into link issues. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <occi.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace oracle::occi;

Environment * env;
Connection * conn;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::OBJECT);
    conn = env->createConnection("scott", "tiger", "//lcoalhost:1521/xe");
    Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TAB");
    ResultSet *rs=stmt->executeQuery();
    rs->next();
    string ntabs=rs->getString(1);
    cout << "Number of tables " << ntabs << endl;
    conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
    // Close connection etc
    env->terminateConnection(conn);
    Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
    return 0;
}
```

I have the x64 oracle instant client installed in `~/oracle_client`. I can connect to the database using `sqlplus` and `python (cx_Oracle)`.

I am compiling the file with the following command

```
gcc main.cpp -I ~/oracle_client/sdk/include/ -L ~/oracle_client -locci -lclntsh
```

Below is the `ld` error I receive:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file <ORACLE_HOME >/libclntsh.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x62 0x6f 0x6f 0x6b 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x6d 0x61 0x72 0x6b 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): <ORACLE_HOME>/libclntsh.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::allocator::allocator()", referenced from:
_main in ccWf4dno.o
"std::allocator::~allocator()", referenced from:
_main in ccWf4dno.o
"std::basic_ostream >::operator >& (*)(std::basic_ostream >&))", referenced from:
_main in ccWf4dno.o
"std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)", referenced from:
_main in ccWf4dno.o
"std::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
_main in ccWf4dno.o
"std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccWf4dno.o
"std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
___tcf_0 in ccWf4dno.o
"std::cout", referenced from:
_main in ccWf4dno.o
"std::basic_ostream >& std::endl >(std::basic_ostream >&)", referenced from:
_main in ccWf4dno.o
"std::terminate()", referenced from:
_main in ccWf4dno.o
"std::basic_ostream >& std::operator >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*)", referenced from:
_main in ccWf4dno.o
"std::basic_ostream >& std::operator, std::allocator >(std::basic_ostream >&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
_main in ccWf4dno.o
"___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in ccWf4dno.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::allocator::allocator()", referenced from:
_main in ccWf4dno.o
[...]
```

All these undefined symbols are C++ runtime support library functions, unrelated to Oracle.  The simplest and best way to get GCC to bring these in is to link C++ code with the `g++` command, not `gcc`:

```
g++ main.cpp -I ~/oracle_client/sdk/include/ -L ~/oracle_client -locci -lclntsh
```

The linker's architecture warnings about *libclntsh.dylib* are just warnings, so it's possible that the instant client you've installed contains the right architecture as well as the stuff it's complaining about.  In any case, having got rid of these spurious C++ runtime linking problems, you'll be in a better position to debug any remaining Oracle linking problems.

Comment: The instant client comes in distinct 32-bit and 64-bit versions, they don't contain both. With that issue avoided with `-m32` or `-m64` only those errors remain. You are quite right, using `g++` does fix that - but you need both.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like you either installed the 32-bit instant client, in which case you can only build 32-bit binaries and therefore need to add a `-m32` flag to `gcc`; or you installed the 64-bit instant client and `gcc` is defaulting to 32-bit for some reason (such as an alias), in which case you can override with a `-m64` flag.

Either way, your instant client *appears* to be the wrong architecture... and actually from the `x86_64` in your error message, you're building in 64-bit mode, therefore you seem to have installed the 32-bit instant client. But you said in the question that you did install the 64-bit version, which you can verify (as you probably know) with:

```
$ file ~/oracle_client/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
```

... which will end with `x86_64` if it is 64-bit. Since it isn't complaining about `libocci.dylib` it seems to be able to cope with that, suggesting a kind of hybrid installation. Presumably you've created symbolic links for `libclntsh.dylib` and `libocci.dylib` pointing to the full `.11.1` versions. Is it possible that `libclntsh.dylib` is pointing to a 32-bit version in another directory; or that you'd copied it to that name as a 32-bit and then replaced everything with the 64-bit versions and missed the manually-copied file? What architecture does this show:

```
$ file ~/oracle_client/libclntsh.dylib
```

It still won't compile with that sorted out, but the remaining errors aren't Oracle related as far as I can tell... and as John Marshall pointed out, just switching the command from `gcc` to `g++` resolves the remaining issues.

```
g++ -m32 main.cpp ...
```

... creates an `a.out` if the 32-bit instant client is installed/linked properly.

Just for comparison, using a 32-bit client with a 64-bit build fails:

```
$ g++ -m64 main.cpp -I ~/oracle_client32/sdk/include/ -L ~/oracle_client32 -locci -lclntsh
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/alex/oracle_client32/libocci.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/alex/oracle_client32/libocci.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/alex/oracle_client32/libclntsh.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/alex/oracle_client32/libclntsh.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::Mode, void*, void* (*)(void*, unsigned long), void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned long), void (*)(void*, void*))", referenced from:
      _main in ccWD5dXB.o
  "oracle::occi::Environment::terminateEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccWD5dXB.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using a 64-bit client with a 32-bit build fails:

```
$ g++ -m32 main.cpp -I ~/oracle_client64/sdk/include/ -L ~/oracle_client64 -locci -lclntsh
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/alex/oracle_client64/libocci.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/alex/oracle_client64/libocci.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/alex/oracle_client64/libclntsh.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/alex/oracle_client64/libclntsh.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::Mode, void*, void* (*)(void*, unsigned long), void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned long), void (*)(void*, void*))", referenced from:
      _main in ccuBypLo.o
  "oracle::occi::Environment::terminateEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccuBypLo.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But notice that both complain about both libraries, not just `libclntsh`. Using a 32-bit client and 32-bit build, or 64-bit client and 64-bit build, both work:

```
$ g++ -m32 main.cpp -I ~/oracle_client32/sdk/include/ -L ~/oracle_client32 -locci -lclntsh
$ file a.out
a.out: Mach-O executable i386

$ g++ -m64 main.cpp -I ~/oracle_client64/sdk/include/ -L ~/oracle_client64 -locci -lclntsh
$ file a.out
a.out: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```